# Python addition math quiz

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

Just learning python and I'm trying to make an extremely simple math quiz but when running I get a syntax error please explain what I have done wrong

```
from random import randint
inf = 0
while inf < 10:
    num1 = randint(0,5000)
    num2 = randint(0,5000)
    ans = num1+num2
    print(num1,"+",num2)
    plrans = input(int()"What's the answer?")
    if plrans = ans
        print("Correct!")
    else
        print("Incorrect :(")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! What's the error, exactly? Add the trace to your question with the [edit] link.

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: Hint: look at `plrans = input(int()"What's the answer?")`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. The conversion to `int` should be done after getting the input from the user
2. `=` is the assignment operator. In order to check for equality you should use the `==` operator
3. Your `if` statement is missing a colon (`:`)
4. So is your `else` statement:

```
from random import randint
inf = 0
while inf < 10:
    num1 = randint(0,5000)
    num2 = randint(0,5000)
    ans = num1+num2
    print(num1,"+",num2)
    plrans = int(input("What's the answer?")) # issue 1
    if plrans == ans : # issues 2 and 3
        print("Correct!")
    else: # issue 4
        print("Incorrect :(")
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the errors Mureinik listed, you run your `while` loop as long as `inf<10`, but you actually never increment `inf`. So this program would run forever if the other errors were fixed.

Comment: This was the point i wanted it to run forever, but if you could would you please tell me how to increment easily?

Comment: If you put `inf+=1` at the end of the loop, the program will end after doing ten quizzes.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 errors:

1. plrans = input(int()"What's the answer?")

should be

```
plrans = int(input("What's the answer?"))
```

2. Use `==` instead of `=`.
3. You are missing colons after `if` and `else`.

Comment: That was one of the problems, but now im getting an error at the 
"if plrans = ans:"

Comment: Use `==`. Have you programmed before?